# TTL value of an entry in Map is changed for every update of that entry

Tags: hazelcast, ttl, hazelcast-imap

I am trying to use Hazelcast Map and found that `Expiration time for an entry = Last Updated Time + TTL`.

1. But i want to have it as `Expiration Time for an entry = Creation Time + TTL`. Can some one suggest how to achieve this functionality??
2. This behavior was existing previously, any reason why it got changed?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior has indeed changed since version 3.3.3. Apparently, the previous behavior is [considered a bug](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/3920) by the community.

Possibilities:

1. Open a github issue and it could get implemented if you attract enough supporters
2. Continue using 3.3.2 (doesn't look very compelling but it's also a possibility)
3. Split your map in two ("immutable" and mutable) and only access the second one after checking that the key exists in the first one. When you want to update the value, only do it in the second one. This way, since you're not updating the first map at all, entry will expire `ttl` after creation time.

Answer (score 0):

Its an old thread but maybe this solution can help someone. I faced same scenario with hazelcast 3.7.x. Here is what i did

1. I am Using IMap which provide method to set entry with ttl

   set(K key, V value, long ttl, TimeUnit ttlUnit)

using this method you can make entry with this ttl which will update expiration time accordingly.

2. Now trick is to adjust ttl so that expiration time will not get changed (or ttl will not get updated when entry updated). I did

   ttl=myImap.getEntryView(key).getExpirationTime()- new java.util.Date().getTime();
   myImap.set(key,value,ttl,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

Its tried and tested with hazelcast 3.7.5 . However because of this adjustment to ttl it may cause difference of some milliseconds in expiration date.